# Mac OS - Failed to install mongodb with Homebrew due to Permission Issue

Tags: mongodb, macos, permissions, homebrew

I followed the [official guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) to install mongodb but failed many times.
Firstly, I tried to use brew install mongodb

```
brew --version
Homebrew 1.4.3
brew install mongodb
```

Error:

```
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/scons.formula.lock
```

I tried to use sudo

```
sudo brew install mongodb
```

Error:

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
```

I am still trying to download the binaries and extracted through the tar command, but it is more complicated and I encountered many other problems. So I hope to solve this problem firstly... Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local

Comment: It works!!  It seems to be a problem with homebrew

Comment: Homebrew does not allow you to use sudo, so the ownership permissions of the file/folder has to be changed.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot :)

Comment: You might also try docker for that purpose. I have an alias for docker-compose (`docker-sys` I call it) and have all these services I need specified in it. It helps me keep the system clean and version jumps and so are much easier.

Comment: Do you mean this ---- https://github.com/docker/compose ?

Comment: @Pavilion yes, I am using that for my local setup. Services are running in `docker`, stuff I develop is either in `docker` or `vagrant`.

Comment: @Pavilion if you are interested, join me on [the Docker room of chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76919/docker) and I'm happy to describe my setup.

Comment: @balintant Thanks a lot. I have visited the website. But I don't have enough reputation to talk there. I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: @Pavilion I created a [new Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163231/mac-os-failed-to-install-mongodb-with-homebrew-due-to-permission-issue) and will post my solution and the reasons I decided to use this solution there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
```

**Update:**

Whilst the above solves your issue just fine, there is a much nicer way.

```sh
# allow admins to manage homebrew's local install directory
chgrp -R admin /usr/local
chmod -R g+w /usr/local

# allow admins to homebrew's local cache of formulae and source files
chgrp -R admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
chmod -R g+w /Library/Caches/Homebrew

# if you are using cask then allow admins to manager cask install too
chgrp -R admin /opt/homebrew-cask
chmod -R g+w /opt/homebrew-cask
```

source: https://gist.github.com/jaibeee/9a4ea6aa9d428bc77925

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck in a bit of a loop with permissions issues. I eventually uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew and it worked for me. Here's a reference: https://github.com/Homebrew/install